# html page with javascript not running on oukitel phone, does anybody know why?

Tags: javascript, android

When I look at the details of the file I just copied from my computer to the oukitel phone, it says "executable: no", and does not execute any of the javascript. I mean I open the file through firefox and it does not execute any of the javascript.

The same file, copied to a Samsung phone works almost fine (except the links to other pages).

Any clue as to why on one phone it runs and not in the other?

Any hints as how to solve it?

Comment: No sage around that can shed some light into this matter? My question goes for any android phone, maybe you know some way to make a program html + javascript to work by just copying it into the device and opening it with the browser. Thanks!

Comment: Now I see that maybe my question was not so well worded, and maybe that was the reason nobody could answer it. My apologies for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting the error message “Access to the file was denied”, I found the solution in this post:

https://linuxnorth.wordpress.com/2016/08/08/opening-local-html-files-in-firefox-under-android-6-0-marshmallow/

I quote:

"The fix is fairly simple. Load Android’s “Settings” menu and navigate to “Apps”. Scroll down to “Firefox”. Tap the Firefox listing to bring up the “App Info” screen. Click on the “Permissions” option, and slide the control for “Storage” to the right to enable file permissions."

I did that and its working! :) Thanks to the guy that posted it!!